# How to port kylix3 gui project (c++) to any other c++ supported gui ide in linux?

Tags: c++builder

I have an existing very old source code which was written in kylix 3 (C++ builder) IDE in red hat Linux. Now I want to port this code to new IDE because of kylix 3 and Borland C++ builder are no longer available for Linux.  So I am searching for the solution or any idea for the same. In existing ide there is **.bpr** project file and source code has **.cpp** file which generated by form screens. 
 I have tried with Qt creator but there is no such conversion option in Qt creator. So I was trying to replicate the UI code by rewriting as a new project but not sure it would be the right solution.

So please give some suggestions so I can find the solution.

Comment: Please avoid adding `Thanks in advance` or `Regards`. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: C++ Builder now uses FireMonkey to support multiple platforms. Try FMX for Linux. It would probably help you to transfer a decent amount of code without rewriting.

Comment: C++ builder does not support for Linux , I tried to add platform Linux but the option is not available . Though I set up a 64 bit Linux platform while installation. I have installed the trial version of c++ builder with rad studio